# D7 update field in database problem

Tags: 7, entities

```
function sms_user_delete($uid, $number = FALSE) {
  userfieldmobil_user_update($account->uid); // my custom field about users i call this manually. 
  $query = db_delete('sms_user')
    ->condition('uid', $uid);
  if ($number) {
    $query->condition('number', $number);
  }
  $num_deleted = $query->execute();
}

function userfieldmobil_user_update($uid) { // i make it manually not able to update this
$num_updated = db_update('field_data_field_mobilnumber')
->fields(array(
'field_mobilnumber_value' => '',
))
->condition('entity_id', $uid, '>=')
->execute();
}
```

What i'm doing wrong sms_user delete OK but my custom field has value but not updated.

Comment: are you trying to set `field_mobilnumber_value` to `'nothing  '` when user deleted?

Comment: thanks because uid is null if i dont write in sms_user_delete you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update your field when user was deleted you should put your `update` query into your `sms_user_delete`. Because `userfieldmobil_user_update` will only works if u update user data, not delete it.

```
function sms_user_delete($uid, $number = FALSE) {
  userfieldmobil_user_update($account->uid); // my custom field about users i call this manually. 
  $query = db_delete('sms_user')
    ->condition('uid', $uid);
  if ($number) {
    $query->condition('number', $number);
  }
  $num_deleted = $query->execute();

  $num_updated = db_update('field_data_field_mobilnumber')
     ->fields(array(
     'field_mobilnumber_value' => '',
     ))
     ->condition('entity_id', $uid, '>=')
     ->execute();
  }
```

Its not like in `drupal 6` where u can use `hook_user`, read about [hook_user_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) and [hook_user_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7) for more info.